# Surf plot does not display colors correctly

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

This is the graph I get
[image]

The values I have for the graph are all close to **1**. So I expected the graph to be mainly in **red**. Why does it show in blue?  What does this colour bar mean ? What does this graph actually mean?

Values are
 Columns 1 through 10

```
     0    1.0000         0         0         0    1.0000       NaN    0.8634    0.9872       NaN
     0    1.0000         0         0         0    1.0000       NaN    0.8634    0.9872       NaN
     0    1.0000         0         0         0    1.0000       NaN    0.8634    0.9872       NaN
   NaN         0       NaN       NaN       NaN         0       NaN         0         0       NaN
     0    1.0000         0         0         0    1.0000       NaN    0.8634    0.9872       NaN
     0    1.0000         0         0         0    1.0000       NaN    0.8634    0.9872       NaN
   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
     0    1.0000         0         0         0    1.0000       NaN    0.8634    0.9872       NaN
   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is one **patch**. And a patch by default just has **one color**, determined by the z-level of the first point used to create the patch.

To solve the problem **interpolate** the face color by using the according property.

```
surf(X,'FaceColor','interp')
```

[image]

---

Alternatively interpolate your data to fit a much finer mesh. And looking at your data, I'm not sure if if `surf` is the right choice at all.

Comment: Thank You . I used as `surf(X,Y,Z,'FaceColor','interp')` and it gives a graph that is more closer to what I expected. But what does `'FaceColor','interp'` does?Why do you say that `surf` might not the right choice? What graph would be better then

Comment: It does interpolate your z-data to a finer grid. I just couldn't see any information in your plot. But as I don't know what you want to achieve, I can't judge.